# Toggle comment shortcut in netbeans python?

Tags: python, netbeans, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

In netbeans the toggle comments shortcut is <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>, which works well for php and ruby but for python it simply does nothing, can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of NetBeans are you using?

I just tried it in NetBeans 6.9 and it works perfectly in Python source

(I presume you have Python plugin installed )
Version: 0.105 Source: NetBeans Beta
Plugin Description
Python support: editing, refactoring, hints, etc.

Comment: In that case, the issue might be with my netbeans. I am using NetBeans IDE 6.10 M1 (Build 201008260001)

Comment: Try reinstalling the plugin, but I strongly suggest upgrading to 6.9 or 7.0 .. Especially since you are using M1 version .